# Oracle SQL developer 23.1 Unable to use software due to incompatible version errors

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting the following errors, probably due to the same issue:

1. When I click on connection, then type the password I get:

   **An error was encountered performing the requested operation:Invalid Oracle URL specified
   Vendor code 17067**
2. Next I right click the properties for the connection, then when I attempt to test the connection I get the following error:

   **Status : Failure -Test failed: Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:218000, Jdbc-OCI:2110000**

I've installed Oracle SQL developer 23.1 on Windows 11 machine. I also downloaded the instant client instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru. I added the system PATH to this instant client. I'm using TNSNAMES.ora file. I went even further to install older versions or SQL-D and instant client and same errors - well incompatible versions are different.

How do I correctly install compatible software versions on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the jdbc driver and add it to your Instant Client root directory.

- Download: [ojdbc11.jar](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/jdbc/219/ojdbc11.jar)

For some reason this wasn't included in the Instant Client, but it is available in the full Oracle Client.

[I show how here, step by step.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2023/05/sql-developer-23-1-and-the-instant-client/)

You can confirm it's working (you have a THICK, or OCI, connection) using the 'show connection' or 'show jdbc' command in your SQL Worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. I followed the instructions - I was unable to find the BIN directory under the instantclient folder so I just dropped it in root of the that folder, restarted the machine just in case, however I'm getting the same two errors above. I re-downloaded the SQL-D 23.1 again just in case but did not help. Is the full Oracle client available for download so I can at least try that?

Comment: What does the Test button show in your preferences, Database, Advanced page where you setup the Instant Client? Best guess is your PATH isn't good.

Comment: I got the following: `Testing the Instant Client located at C:\....\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_21_10
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
Driver version: 21.9.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... Failed:
Error loading the native OCI libraryThe native OCI driver could not be loaded`

Comment: Client folder seems to be in the PATH (I removed the other stuff): `java.library.path = ....;C:\....\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_21_10;....`

Comment: So after it failed by testing it few times in the 'Configure Oracle Client'. I changed the 'Client type'=**Oracle home** and 'Client Location'=**C:\....\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_21_10**, clicked OK. Then I checked the 'Use Oracle Client' and 'Use OCI/Thick driver' as well as specified 'Tnsnames directory', then closed the dialog.

Comment: Then on left hand side in the 'Oracle Connections', I right clicked the connection, added the password and tried to connect and it connected successfully. For the same connection properties in the 'New/Select Database connection' dialog box, I put in the password and clicked the test button and Status:Success. I'm not quite sure how its working now. What am I missing? Is it still the PATH issue?

Comment: move that client up to the first thing in the PATH

Comment: I moved the oracleclient entry in the system PATH to the top on the first line and rebooted the machine. However the same issue/errors in the 'Configure Oracle Client' dialog. I can add screenshots if that would help.

Comment: Please start a thread on our community forums - https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/sql_developer?tags=sql-developer

Comment: I've started the thread on oracle forums: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-developer-23-1-error-loading-the-native-oci-library-8481